# css table cell unnecessary padding in IE 11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, internet-explorer

I have a small table and the internet explorer 11 adds padding to the cells so the hole table is bigger than in chrome or firefox.

Does someone know why its happend? Im using bootstrap 3.

Hier is a example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cX8N9eLjVTR93nYyaLTN?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td width="25px">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100%" type="range" >
        </td>
        <td width="25px">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">-</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <small class="pull-left">24,0 °C</small>
            <small class="pull-right">31,1 °C</small>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

IE 11:

[image]

and chrome:

[image]

Comment: If you post a working code snippet we most likely will be able to give a proper answer

Comment: I updatet my question with an plnkr example. The Margin between the Text and Slider is bigger in ie than in chrome ... and i dont how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is putting more padding on the `<input>` than what Chrome is. Chrome is putting 8px of padding on both the top and bottom, IE is putting 17px on the top and 32px on the bottom. Set the padding on the input so it's consistent across browsers, and you should be all set.